# How to compile a yacc (.y) file using Bison in Windows environment?

Tags: windows-7, bison, lex

I've read http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/bison/bison_5.html#SEC25. But following those instruction i can not compile my yacc file using `bison`

How do i compile my file in windows 7 ... ?

Please help me to do this.

Comment: Do you have any details of how it failed? It's hard to tell what your problem is from here.

Comment: @David :Actually i'm new to the bison world. I donot know the commands to compile a `.y` file. I think those comments are for Unix environment. And i've downloaded the bison .exe from [ http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/ ]

Comment: You've got bison.exe from the right place. So what's wrong?

Comment: @ David : i tried to compile the `.y` file using the `bison -d -o a.c a.y`. its not producing any file( `a.c`) its just showing the parsed file in the `command Prompt` . how do i produce `a.c` file .

Answer (score 1):

There is a common reason why bison will not operate properly on Windows and is mentioned in the install instructions but often overlooked. It is important that the name of the location of the directory that bison (and flex) is installed in (the path) does not contain a space. in particular this means that it cannot be placed under `C:\Program Files\`. The problem is that this directory might be suggest as the default install location. It is sometimes necessary to manually change the default to somethings else (like `C:\GnuWin\` or similar). It is also usually necessary to manually add the appropriate directory to the PATH environment variable. Once this has been done there should be no problems in running bison and flex from the command prompt. It would normally be used in the following way:

```
flex lang.l
bison lang.y
gcc -o lang.exe lang.tab.c -lfl
```

It is not necessary to install MinGW, Cygwin or use Powershell or a VM or use linux as indicated by @DavidHefferman

If you still can't get it right, I even have an [instructional video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=58I6nAybzzI&list=PL3czsVugafjNLmIHA8ODBxuwWy8W4Uk9h&index=2)!

Answer (score 0):

Using those Unix commands in Windows PowerShell *might* work, but I'm not sure and I'm currently not on Windows, so I can't check it.

If that fails you could try installing [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/install.html) (a basic Linux environment in Windows). You'd have to select the bison package during installation. It comes with its own shell that you can use.

Actually my personal favorite when programming under Windows is setting up a virtual machine with [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads). That way you could use a real Linux environment without actually leaving Windows.

Good luck!

Comment: absolutely no need for PowerShell, Cygwin, VM etc.